# How to reproduce “Cannot drop database because it is currently in use”?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can anyone please let me know how can I reproduce the error “Cannot drop database because it is currently in use” ?

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be sufficient to open a query window in SQL Server Mgmt Studio and do a `SELECT * FROM sys.tables ` in that database (or basically do whatever you want to do... just *use* the database :-) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
USE {yourDb}
```

It will select your database,then execute

```
DROP DATABASE  {yourDb}
```

returns a message:
Cannot drop database "{yourDb}" because it is currently in use.

Answer (score 3):

Open up the database in SQL Server Management Studio and do say a `select top 1000 rows` on an arbitrary table and leave the window / connection open.

Answer (score 1):

for example:
query database in sql server management studio and dont close query tab. Then try to drop t